# How can I run and test my production locally?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

First of all, thank you ahead of time for any help on this thread. I have been meaning to ask for help with this matter for a while now and thought it was about time I asked.

For the past 6 months I have been working for this company as the only developer (full stack developer). I am running the whole shebang here. Prior to this job I have been able to deploy webapps through UBUNTU on AWS with experience in Django, Nginx, Gunicorn and Angular. Nothing too advanced.

The problem is that for the past 6 months I have been testing and developing through a very tedious manner. I would write a little bit of code, I `git add`,`git commit`, `git push`, and then `git pull` on the server followed by `manage.py collectstatic`. At first I went with it but now I would like to test changes locally and I am not sure how to do that. The webapp is a Django, with AWS MySQL database.

From my personal experience, I was able to run and test my own apps just by a simple `python manage.py runserver` but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I think that you're looking for something like CircleCI.  It allows you to automatically run the full suite of tests whenever you commit, and run tests locally in your dev branch.

Comment: So I am reading abour CircleCI, Jenkins also came up. One of the servers that I have explored in our AWS instances list had Jenkin. I had no idea what that was and how I can make use of it. Do you think that might be my best route to go?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't run locally using runserver.

Comment: When you use `python manage.py test`, a fake database is created. This will throw errors if you can't connect to your _actual_ database, though. Can you connect to your actual database locally?

Comment: I can connect with MySQL Workbench. Let me try `python manage.py test`. Right now I am trying to runserver and I am getting `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/geonameszip/'` everytime I try to load the page.
EDIT: Many errors when I run `python manage.py test`.

Comment: What errors? From my experience, this depends a lot on your setup

Comment: I am now getting `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`